# How to delete Cookies on opening a website // or create alert message

Tags: html, popup

I did mi first HTML website, and it works fine until now. the purpose of the website is, that you can download a Document that I update every Sunday. Now people are saying that they didn't see the new document, and after delete the cookies they can see it...So I have 2 questions

1. Is it possible to write a command or code in the Index.html that deletes the cookies of the user everytime he visits the webpage?
2. Or can I use a pop-up alert where I can tell them to delete the cookies? or whats the best way to do that.

I hope I wrote it understandable.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not so knowledgeable but, I think you can only "unset" the cookies that you yourself have set or set a time limit for the cookies (which it will automatically get deleted after the time limit). Not sure if there is a way to force delete all user's cookies but if you are okay with sticking with a "pop-up alert", you can add this code into your index.html, inside the header tag.

```
<head>
<script>alert('Your-message-to-delete-cookies');</script>
</head>
```

This will pop up a message to those who visit that page